# Can any App Store app access all of my passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management, key-management, macos, keychain

Whilst researching [another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/export-non-extractable-private-key-from-keychain-on-os-x), I've noticed that on OS X 10.9.4 there are many instances of `Library/Keychains/login.keychain` from `~` within the `Data` folder of what looks like apps from Apple App Store within `~/Library/Containers`.

Is this merely a coincidence, or does this mean that any random app from the App Store can so easily get a hold of all of my passwords in one go?

Answer (score 2):

No. Just because there is an alias to something from an app's sandbox container does not mean the App has access to it -- that's still controlled by the app's entitlement list (and I strongly suspect Apple would reject any app that requested direct access to a user's keychain files). Also, even if it could access the file directly (as a non-sandboxed app could), the passwords are encrypted, so it'd still have to get past that layer of security.